# FilePathResult Download Progress MVC

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc

I use this method to download a file

```
public FilePathResult downloadFile(string fileName)
{
    //Download the spreadsheet
    string path = "C:\\Users\\Johandk\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\FormValue\\" + fileName + ".xlsx";
    return File(path, "application/vnd.ms-excel", fileName + ".xlsx");
}
```

Is there any way I can check the download progress or even get notified when the download completes?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to know if the download is complete on the server side or just to notify the client the the file is ready for him?

Comment: Just need to know if the download is completed on the server side

Comment: well you can remove the java script tag, it has nothing to do with your question. how about tapping to the page_unload event, it get fired when all of the request has been rendered. but it will not let you change anything in the response. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.unload(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Detecting the File Download Dialog In the Browser](http://geekswithblogs.net/GruffCode/archive/2010/10/28/detecting-the-file-download-dialog-in-the-browser.aspx)

taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1106377/395890)

Comment: I dont think this is the same thing. The OP wants to know when the download is complete, not when the download is ready to be downloaded

Comment: Just need to know if the download is completed on the server side